# Keynote: Ken Burns Effect within a Masked Image on slide

Tags: graphics, keynote

I have a slide with 3 photos on it.  Each is in a [rectangle mask](https://support.apple.com/guide/keynote/edit-an-image-tan811faceea/mac).

I want to have an animation where all 3 images have a kind of Ken Burns effect - zooming and moving but staying the same size within the mask on the slide.  Kind of like you'd get on a Photos app slideshow presentation.

I understand how I could do this if only 1 image on the slide but is there any way of doing this within a masked image?  When I click on Animate/Scale, the entire masked rectangle gets bigger and not the zoomed photo.

Thanks for the help!